# Spring Integration @ServiceActivator on a Java 8 default interface method

Tags: java, spring, java-8, spring-integration, default-method

I'd like to use the `@ServiceActivator` annotation on a Java 8 default interface method. This default method will delegate to another method of this interface depending on business rules.

```
public interface MyServiceInterface {

    @ServiceActivator
    public default void onMessageReceived(MyPayload payload) {
        if(payload.getAction() == MyServiceAction.MY_METHOD) {
            ...
            myMethod(...);
        }
    }

    public void myMethod(...);
}
```

This interface is then implemented by a Spring `@Service` class:

```
@Service
public class MyService implements MyServiceInterface {

    public void myMethod(...) {
        ...
    }
}
```

When executing the code, this does not work!

I can only get it to work to remove the `@ServiceActivator` annotation from the default method, and override that default method in my `@Service` class and delegate to the super method:

```
@Service
public class MyWorkingService implements MyServiceInterface {

    @ServiceActivator
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MyPayload payload) {
        MyServiceInterface.super.onMessageReceived(payload);
    }

    public void myMethod(...) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Overriding a default method neglects the purpose of a default method.

Is there another way to implement this scenario in a clean manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work now, because Spring Integration relies on the `ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods`, which uses `ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods` and the last one just does this `clazz.getDeclaredMethods()`, which doesn't return those `default` methods on the interface.

Feel free to raise an [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR) issue against Spring Framework to consider that option.

In meantime, right, there is no other choice unless to override that method.

Comment: As I said: it is an SF issue, so moved to the appropriate project: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12822

Comment: Follow up: it has been fixed in Spring 4.2 RC1